# Joomla 'PageNavigation' Plugin

Tags: plugins, joomla

If this isn't possible please let me know!

I'm hoping there's a solution to what I'm asking.

I need to move the **Next/Prev buttons**, located in the pagenavigation plugin to after the `<jdoc:include type="component" />;` Basically render it anywhere in my templates' index.php?

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Pagination is already built into the layouts of the various views it makes sense for. You can move its location around using template overrides.

Comment: Elin. The pagenavigation plugin is located at the bottom of an article post; so it's only output when you have a menu item type as single article. I just need to be able to output the particular pageNavigation buttons somewhere else.

Comment: You unfortunately really need to keep it somewhere inside the single page layout unless you rewrite the whole thing. Going to post a longer answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that renders the pagination:

```
<?php
if (!empty($this->item->pagination) && $this->item->pagination && $this->item->paginationposition && !$this->item->paginationrelative):
    echo $this->item->pagination;
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As you can see the pagination is part of the item. As you can see if you look at the pagenavigation content plugin the pagination values are created in response to the onContentBeforeDisplay event. The plugin is hard coded to only work for articles in the single article view.

So to use it in a different component you would really need to create a second plugin for that component (or you could do any component or anything besides the single article view, that all would be easy to code using context).

To locate it in a different place in the single article view you would have to move the block of code to the desired location in the layout.  Potentially you could also use css to locate the rendering of the block somewhere else on the page. (But more on this at the bottom.)

Unfortunately (but nor surprisingly given its name) onContentBeforeDisplay comes really late, in the view (unlike with pagination in the backend).

I always find it confusing because this frontend "pagination" property controlled by this plugin has nothing to do with backend pagination which is controlled by a JPagination object. I believe if is because of backward compatibility all the way to 1.0. ALso because the template chrome for pagination chrome are called `pagination.php`.

That leads me to the next thing I'll mention. You can make a file `pagination.php` and put it in the html folder of your template. You can see an example of this in the core template protostar.   THat's where you would do the CSS or whatever other tricks you want to do to make the pagination do what you want. I think if you work hard enough at it (possibly using javascript or possibly calling that file from a module) you can pretty much achieve whatever you want.